# Magento Enterprise main content page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.13

We are using Magento Enterprise ver. 1.13.0.2 and i can't find where i have to go to edit the content of the main page? Is it accessible through the Magento dashboard interface?

I have looked through the "CMS -> Pages -> Managed Content". But i could not find it in there.
Nor is it inside of the "CMS -> Static Blocks" page.
Or in any of the System Configuration options.

So i'm thinking i'm going to have to actually edit some code, but i don't know which file that might be.

I really don't know alot about the Magento Enterprise system, so any help would be awesome!

If anyone could help out or point me to documentation on where to find the main content page that would be great! thanks! :)

*edit: by change content i mean i would like to move some things around get rid of a few things and add a new thing or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMS->Pages->UrlKey: home

Have fun!

Comment: I don't have that option avaible.. I only have 
CMS->Pages->Manage Content and
CMS->Pages->Manage Hierarchy

Comment: then goto Manage Content and edit the Page with the url key "home"